# Missing dependencies when generate-module-info jdeps

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system, jdeps

I`m trying to run jdeps with the following command:

```
jdeps --module-path modules --generate-module-info out com.demo.market.jar
```

My `com.demo.market.jar` depends both on application modules and automatic modules.
I put all dependencies in the 'modules' folder but I got an error:

```
Error: missing dependencies
com.demo.market.platform.MarketPlace ->  com.demo.client.wholesale.Client  not found
com.demo.market.platform.MarketPlace ->  com.demo.product.api.Product      not found
com.demo.market.platform.MarketPlace ->  com.demo.product.laptop.Laptop    not found
com.demo.market.collector.ProductsCollector -> com.demo.logistic.DeliveryService not found
com.demo.market.collector.ProductsCollector -> com.demo.product.api.Product      not found
```

But when I add `--add-modules` It works fine.

```
jdeps --module-path modules --add-modules com.demo.client,com.demo.product,com.demo.logistic --generate-module-info out com.demo.market.jar
```

Am I doing something wrong? I supposed that jdeps would find all modules instead of manually add them.

Comment: Does `jdeps --generate-module-info out com.my.app.jar` simply not work for you? What's your path and what modules does it include. Could you share the details for both the command `--module-path` and `--add-modules` as used by you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you execute the following:

```
jdeps --module-path modules --generate-module-info out com.demo.market.jar
```

The modules that are resolved from the directory are *observable modules* which in your case are not able to make it to the set of *root modules*.

---

Over the other part of the question -

```
jdeps --module-path modules --add-modules com.demo.client,com.demo.product,com.demo.logistic --generate-module-info . com.demo.market.jar
```

While on the other hand, adding them explicitly makes sure the modules are present in the set of root modules.

---

As an alternative(from the ***[JEP261#Module System](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261)***, you can try using the command

```
jdeps --module-path modules --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH --generate-module-info out com.demo.market.jar
```

> *As a final special case, at both run time and link time, if  is **ALL-MODULE-PATH** then all observable modules found on the relevant
>   module paths are added to the root set. **ALL-MODULE-PATH** is valid at
>   both compile time and run time. This is provided for use by build
>   tools such as Maven, which already ensure that all modules on the
>   module path are needed. It is also a convenient means to add automatic
>   modules to the root set.*

---

Side note there, in terms of the commands to be executed:-

- Also, the `jdeps` output shared in the question holds true with `-verbose:class` ideally.

Comment: adding `ALL-MODULE-PATH` solved the issue. Thanks. But for me still not clear when I can use just `jdeps --generate-module-info out com.my.app.jar`

Comment: @ZimboRodger Its useful when you lets say migrate an existing jar to Java9 modules and add to it the `module-info.java` as descriptor.

Comment: I mean what should I do to use this command without specifying `--module-path` as you mentioned in your very first [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47500529/missing-dependencies-when-generate-module-info-jdeps/47512109?noredirect=1#comment81961276_47500529)

Comment: The module path is to make sure all the modules that your current artifact depend on are resolved while generating the module-info. The path to look for additionally.

Comment: @Naman, ty for useful information. I tried your solutions, but I'm still getting `not found` for all dependencies inside `selenium-chrome-driver.jar` legacy jar, but for `selenium-api.jar` it works fine, yes.

Comment: @invzbl3 You've got to make sure the modules that it's referring to are present on the module path to ensure they are resolved during the generation.

Comment: @Naman, how to check it correctly? To add each dependency manually via --add-modules as in 2nd line of your answer? I'm getting also `not found` in any cases. E.g. If I write: `--module-path modules --add-modules org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions --generate-module-info ...\selenium selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar`

I get: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions not found`

Comment: @invzbl3 The problem there looks in `--add-modules org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions` which is where you need to specify the ***module** that includes the class `ChromeOptions`* and not the complete class itself.

Comment: @Naman, corrected it to `jdeps --module-path modules --add-modules org.openqa.selenium.chrome --generate-module-info C:\...\selenium selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar` the same issue. And tried by the same logic, but instead of `org.openqa.selenium.chrome` I wrote this `org.openqa.selenium` as one level higher also `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.openqa.selenium not found`

Comment: @Naman, using ALL-MODULE-PATH option, I get a lot of "not found".

Comment: It is hard to make sense of this answer. The observable modules do not "make it" into the root set. From what I understand, the root set is given, and the very job of jdep is to construct a dependency graph for it from the observable set. The error would only make sense if the dependencies actually absent from the module-path. And then add-modules seem to break this presence check.