# Unable generating module-info for legacy jar via jdeps using Java 11

Tags: java, jdeps

I need to generate *module-info* file for legacy jar which named as:
*selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar* using the command:

```
jdeps --module-path modules --generate-module-info out selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar
```

But I'm getting as result:

```
Missing dependence: C:\...\selenium.chrome.driver\module-info.java not generated
Error: missing dependencies
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver            -> com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap             not found
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver            -> org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities                   not found
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver            -> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException             not found
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver            -> org.openqa.selenium.html5.LocalStorage             not found
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver            -> org.openqa.selenium.html5.Location                 not found
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver            -> org.openqa.selenium.html5.LocationContext          not found
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver            -> org.openqa.selenium.html5.SessionStorage           not found
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver            -> org.openqa.selenium.html5.WebStorage               not found
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver            -> org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen    not found
...
```

I tried as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47512109/8370915) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080660/how-to-build-java-9-dependencies-from-maven-dependencies/47080726#47080726):

```
jdeps --module-path modules --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH --generate-module-info out selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar
```

Then I'm getting the same error.

As alternative way, I tried to add separately modules like:

```
jdeps --module-path modules --add-modules  org.openqa.selenium.chrome,org.openqa.selenium.remote --generate-module-info out selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar
```

And I see this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.openqa.selenium.chrome not found
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findFail(Resolver.java:877)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:128)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:411)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:245)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsConfiguration.<init>(JdepsConfiguration.java:117)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsConfiguration$Builder.build(JdepsConfiguration.java:563)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.buildConfig(JdepsTask.java:589)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:543)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:519)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.Main.main(Main.java:49)
```

And no matter which module I'll add, the issue will be always as:

```
java.lang.module.FindException name_of_your_module
```

Using one level higher didn't help me also:

```
jdeps --module-path modules --add-modules  org.openqa.selenium --generate-module-info out selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar
```

The error will be:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.openqa.selenium not found
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findFail(Resolver.java:877)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:128)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:411)
```

So, the last thing that I can do is to create module-info manually and write inside each module using `exports`?

**Updated:**

```
jdeps -cp guava-25.0-jre.jar;selenium-api-3.141.59.jar;selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar
```

To find classes via [-cp](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jdeps.html#GUID-A543FEBE-908A-49BF-996C-39499367ADB4) option:

```
selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar -> guava-25.0-jre.jar
selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar -> java.base
selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar -> selenium-api-3.141.59.jar
selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar -> selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar
```

I have added to `selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar`, `selenium-api-3.141.59.jar` also `guava-25.0-jre.jar` and `selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar`.

Comment: Your `jdeps` command includes the option `--module-path modules` - for this to work, there needs to be a folder `modules` in the directory where you execute the command that contains all dependencies of the Selenium Chrome driver. Is that the case?

Comment: @Nicolai, E.g. I have selenium jar file inside: `C:\Users\invzbl3\Desktop\modules`.I'm using the command `jdeps --module-path modules --generate-module-info out selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar` there.  And also `Error: missing dependencies`. What's interesting it happens exactly for `selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar` file, if I do the same actions for `selenium-api-3.141.59.jar` it works good. I don't understand what is the difference.

Answer (score 1):

File `selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar` is **not** a modular JAR since it does not contain any *module info* like a `module-info.class` file.

For me, `jdeps` worked when I used the `-cp` option and added the dependent JARS, like so...

```
jdeps -cp guava-25.0-jre.jar;selenium-api-3.141.59.jar;selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar
```

And I got this output...

```
selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar -> guava-25.0-jre.jar
selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar -> java.base
selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar -> selenium-api-3.141.59.jar
selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar -> selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> com.google.common.base                             guava-25.0-jre.jar
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> com.google.common.collect                          guava-25.0-jre.jar
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> com.google.common.io                               guava-25.0-jre.jar
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> java.io                                            java.base
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> java.lang                                          java.base
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> java.lang.invoke                                   java.base
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> java.util                                          java.base
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> java.util.function                                 java.base
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> java.util.stream                                   java.base
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> org.openqa.selenium                                selenium-api-3.141.59.jar
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> org.openqa.selenium.html5                          selenium-api-3.141.59.jar
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> org.openqa.selenium.interactions                   selenium-api-3.141.59.jar
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> org.openqa.selenium.mobile                         selenium-api-3.141.59.jar
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> org.openqa.selenium.remote                         selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> org.openqa.selenium.remote.html5                   selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> org.openqa.selenium.remote.http                    selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> org.openqa.selenium.remote.mobile                  selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar
   org.openqa.selenium.chrome                         -> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service                 selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Abra. I know that this is not modular JAR, so I'm trying to generate for this jar module-info file to use it in Java 11 project. But all commands don't work for me in this way. if -cp option is for finding classes then how it helps to get module-info file? Because I have: `-classpath cannot be used with --generate-module-info option`.