# Why does jdeps issue a warning about a split package?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, jdeps

I have a simple non-modular jar file `main.jar` that depends on `libA.jar` and `libB.jar`. These three jar files all reside in the current directory. I want jdeps (version 15.0.1) to generate a `module-info.java` file for `main.jar`. Here's my shell command (using cmd.exe on Windows):

```
jdeps --module-path .  --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH --generate-module-info . main.jar
```

This command indeed produces the desired `module-info.java` file but also issues this warning:

```
Warning: split package: org.example.main file:///D:/Temp/./main.jar main.jar
writing to .\main\module-info.java
```

The package `org.example.main` does only exist in `main.jar` - so I reckon there should be no warning.

Any hints as to why jdeps does see a problem here ?

Comment: what is your `--module-path` and why are you trying to generate the module-info in the same folder as it (`.`)? you can refer to a sample command in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47512109/1746118)

Comment: @Naman: I tried to keep it simple and put the jar files `libA.jar`, `libB.jar` (on which `main.jar` depends) and `main.jar` in the current directory. If I put only `libA.jar` and `libB.jar` in a new subfolder `modules` and run `jdeps --module-path modules  --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH --generate-module-info . main.jar` the warning disappears. But I still don't get why it appeared when all jars resided in the same directory.

Comment: I cannot really say much about why it warned while other jars were there. Maybe a reproducible example over GitHub can help explain things better?